# How to speed up exploration of data in HDFS by streaming?

Tags: hadoop, streaming, hdfs

I have some fields that I want to extract out of hdfs.

Currently I'm doing `hadoop fs -text /path/to/20120903/*-* 2>/dev/null | awk -F '\t' '{ print $16 }' | sort | uniq > users-0903`.

How could I speed this up (need to do it for 0904, 0905... and this takes some time)?

I had some Hadoop streaming attempts, but it didn't seem to like most of the scripts I gave to it, so I gave up. How would you attempt this task using streaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way to do this using Hadoop Streaming would be:

`hadoop jar hadoop-streaming.jar -input /path/to/2012093 -output /path/to/output-0903 -mapper "awk -F '\t' '{print \$16}'" -reducer 'uniq'`

Or better written:

```
hadoop jar hadoop-streaming.jar \
  -input /path/to/2012093 \
  -output /path/to/output-0903 \
  -mapper "awk -F '\t' '{print \$16}'"\
  -reducer 'uniq'
```

The mapper will emit the 16th word between tabs as the key with no value.  It will then get sorted during shuffle/sort and the call to `uniq` will get each key/value pair which are just repeats of the key.  These will be reduced to one copy by `uniq`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the implicit shuffle/sort.